# Case Statement having no effect on output

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am trying to get sums of donations based on the bank approval status and grouped by gift kind. However, it the script outputs RR and NR donations on separate lines (see below the script). It seems like the case statements aren't working at all.

```
select gift_kind,
    case
        when c.bank_approval_status = 'AP' then 
            sum(c.charge_amount) end approved,  
    case    
        when c.bank_approval_status in ('RR','NR') then 
            sum(c.charge_amount) end rejected,
    case    
        when c.bank_approval_status = 'AR' then 
            sum(c.charge_amount)*-1 end refunded,
    case 
        when c.bank_approval_status not in ('AR','AP','RR','NR')  then 
            sum(c.charge_amount) end other_status
from charge_log c, transactions t
where c.account_id=t.account_id
and c.process_id= 'CHG - 02532'
and c.gift_date=t.gift_date
and c.gift_seq=t.gift_seq
and C.PLEDGE_NUMBER=t.pledge_number
and t.sts='A'
group by  t.fund_type, t.gift_kind, c.bank_approval_status
order by gift_kind asc
```

Comment: Put the `case` inside the `sum()` functions, e.g.: `sum(case when c.bank_approval_status = 'AP' then c.charge_amount end)`

Comment: ...and use `else` for the final clause.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for this logic:

```
select gift_kind,
       sum(case when c.bank_approval_status = 'AP' then c.charge_amount 
           end) as approved,  
       sum(case when c.bank_approval_status in ('RR', 'NR') then c.charge_amount
           end) as rejected,
       sum(case when c.bank_approval_status in ('AR') then c.charge_amount*-1
           end) as refunded,
       sum(case when c.bank_approval_status not in ('AR','AP','RR','NR') then c.charge_amount
           end) other_status
from charge_log c join
     transactions t
     on c.account_id = t.account_id and
        c.gift_date = t.gift_date and
        c.gift_seq = t.gift_seq and
        C.PLEDGE_NUMBER = t.pledge_number
where c.process_id = 'CHG - 02532' and t.sts = 'A'
group by t.fund_type, t.gift_kind
order by gift_kind asc
```

Notes:

- Learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- The `JOIN` conditions should all be in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause.
- The `CASE` is an argument to the `SUM()`.
- Remove the `bank_approval_status` from the `GROUP BY`.
- I don't know why `fund_type` is in the `GROUP BY`.  You may have a reason for that so I left it.

Comment: Thanks so much, Gordon, this does exactly what I needed it to. I'll definitely take those notes to heart, as well - I'm learning on the job here, so feedback like yours is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `case` clauses inside the sums, and add `else 0` to make sure you don't get `null` as a result:

```
sum(case
    when c.bank_approval_status = 'AP' then 
        c.charge_amount else 0 end) approved,  
sum(case    
    when c.bank_approval_status in ('RR','NR') then 
        c.charge_amount else 0 end) rejected,
sum(case    
    when c.bank_approval_status = 'AR' then 
        -c.charge_amount else 0 end) refunded,
sum(case 
    when c.bank_approval_status not in ('AR','AP','RR','NR')  then 
        c.charge_amount else 0 end) other_status
```

And your `group by` should rarely be on columns you use in aggregations (here `bank_approval_status` in the `sum`). Change to:

```
group by  gift_kind
```

Depending on your scheme, other fields might need to be added to the `group by` clause but then it would make sense to also put them in the `select` and `order by` clauses.

Comment: And also to fix the GROUP BY

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that, @MatBailie

Comment: Thanks for commenting! However, I substituted in your script and still got the RR and NR donations broken up instead of summed together. Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: It's your `group by` that makes them split, see last edit to my answer.